# How to locate an element having href='#' attribute in anchor tag

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

```html
<a href="#" id="contact-groups">abc</a>
```

I am not able to locate above element. I tried `//*[@id="contact-groups"]`, but with no success.

Comment: Did you try? `by.id(contact-groups)`

Comment: i cant use this as the framework we designed only support xpath locators

Comment: Try :  `//a[starts-with(@href, "abc")] `

Comment: Do you need to build xpath using only href? You can try with contain text or give parent HTML code or total Dom to figure it out

Comment: Whats your exact requirement, why don't you try:  `//a[@id='contact-groups']` if you only want to identify this element?

Answer (score 0):

Well, XPath is not the best of the methods to find elements. But following will match the links with href = "#".

```
//a[@href="#"]
```

Not sure if your scenario is as simple as your question. I did test this with a simple html page.

Answer (score 0):

The locator seems correct. You could try this too:
.//*[@id='contact-groups']

Answer (score 0):

As per HTML code provided you can try below xpaths

//a[@id='contact-groups']

//a[contains(text(),'abc')]

//a[@href='#']

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the link is in an Iframe.

Use the following code to switch to the frame and then click on the link

```
driver.switchTo().frame("frame-name");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='contact-groups']")).click();
```